# CSS: Position sticky to bottom when enter viewport

Tags: css

I am trying to add a sticky element that stays on the bottom of the page only when it enters the viewport. The idea is that the element would be placed somewhere in the middle of the page and would not be shown immediately when the user visits the page.

Here's my progress so far:

```css
div {
height: 300px;
}

.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100vw;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div style="background: red;">Scroll</div>
<div style="height: 300px; background: orange;"></div>
<div class="sticky">Sticky Section</div>
<div style="background: green;"></div>
<div style="background: blue;"></div>
```

The problem is that my code does the opposite of what I want it to do. The element should only stick past its original location.

Changing `bottom: 0` to `top: calc(100vh - 30px)` on `.sticky` seems to work fine on desktop, but I noticed it's not adequate for Safari on iOS. With this 'hacked' solution, whenever the user scrolls up, the bottom bar increases in size and forces the sticky element to jump.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Sticky position can be a little confusing and frustrating at times.

The key to solving this problem is to keep in mind that a sticky element will appear at the top of its parent element. So by splitting or encapsulating the page's content into 2 sections we can create your desired outcome.

The first section contains content and no sticky element,

The second section contains content and the desired sticky element which will appear at the top of this element

We can decide where on the page the sticky element first appears by where we create the split between the 2 sections or more appropriately where the 2 section starts.

Below is example code where the sticky element appears in the middle of the page.

//

```css
.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100vw;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!-- Content you want before the sticky element -->
<div>
  <div style="height: 300px; background: red;">Scroll</div>
  <div style="height: 300px; background: orange;"></div>
</div>

<!-- Content you want after the sticky element -->
<div>
  <!-- The sticky element will appear as if its been placed here -->
  <div style="height: 300px; background: green;"></div>
  <div style="height: 300px; background: blue;"></div>
  <div class="sticky">Sticky Section</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MaxMa awesome, glad my answer helped. I was actually working on a sticky position stuff yesterday how sp00ky hahaha

Comment: Does this work for folks? I fail to observe the yellow "Sticky Section" sticking to the bottom of the viewport once it's in view (instead it scrolls along with the other elements). [Chrome 96.0.4664.55] [macOS Version 12.0.1]

Comment: Sorry mate, it's not working working for me

Comment: @CedricAmaya @Mernlin Looks like recent browser updates broke the original solution. To resolve it, you'll need to move `<div class="sticky">Sticky Section</div>` to the bottom of the wrapper.