# How come position sticky bottom not work?

Tags: css

In my example below, you can see the sticky top is working perfectly well(scroll down) but the bottom is not.

Can someone explain why the bottom would not stick?

Thank you

```css
#test {
  display: flex;
}

#top {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

#bottom {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div id="col1">
    test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>
  </div>
  <div id="col2">
    <div id="top">top</div>
    <div id="bottom">bottom</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55965662/if-you-specify-bottom-0-for-position-sticky-why-is-it-doing-something-diffe

Comment: The accepted answer here gives a pretty good breakdown of why this happens [CSS: Position sticky to bottom when enter viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54471322/css-position-sticky-to-bottom-when-enter-viewport)

Comment: Yes I have noticed with content inside, it works as expected. Thanks